Laravel Excel can't setting secondary axis when export excel

I want create a chart to excel and i used PhpSpreadsheet 1.29.0 but i can't set secondary axis to it
My code here but it not working
$series = new DataSeries(
    Type::CHART_COLUMN,
    Type::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,
    range(0, 2),
    [$categories],
    [$values1],
    null,
    null,
    'Primary Axis Series'
);

